# Apple Passbook iBeacon message length

Tags: iphone, passbook, ibeacon

When creating a Passbook, you can specify a beacon to trigger a msg on the home screen. The text for the message is defined in relevantText.

```
"beacons":[
   {"proximityUUID":"MyBeaconUUID",
    "relevantText":"Mr. O'Sullivan, welcome to the biggest shopping mall in the great big wide world."
   }],
```

The problem is that the number of characters available for the message is limited to around 25.  My questions are, 
A) Is there any way to set font size
B) Is there anyway to get the text to wordwrap
C) Is there any way to get the full msg displayed after the user slides right to display the Passbook.

Comment: Hi - you are limited to 23 characters for a Passbook lock screen alert (it's the same whether triggered by a beacon, geolocation or time alert). You can't currently change the font size or get the text to word-wrap.  You can display whatever messages you like on the back of a Pass - however these will not be modified due to a beacon alert - they must be defined in advance. Your server will not be notified when a beacon alert occurs - you therefore do not have an opportunity to send a push update at this time ..

Comment: @AndrewPhillips - This looks like the right answer, can you paste this in as an Answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are limited to 23 characters for a Passbook lock screen alert (it's the same whether triggered by a beacon, geolocation or time alert). You can't currently change the font size or get the text to word-wrap. You can display whatever messages you like on the back of a Pass - however these will not be modified due to a beacon alert - they must be defined in advance. Your server will not be notified when a beacon alert occurs - you therefore do not have an opportunity to send a push update at this time .